# Powershell: How to Delete a User Profile

Tags: powershell, permissions, user-profile, terminal-services

I'm trying to delete unused user profiles off a terminal services server to gain some free space. However, I can't seem to find a way to delete the AppData folder as I keep getting "Access Denied" errors. I was wondering if anyone had a technique around this issue?

```
$removefolder = [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath("\\server1\c$\users\" + $folder.name)
Remove-Item $removefolder -recurse -force
```

Remove-Item : Access to the path '\server1\c$\users\user1\AppData\Local\Application Data' is denied.

Comment: Use an account that has access...? Take ownership of the directory first?

Comment: look for the owner / permissions

Comment: arco444, I'm running the script as Administrator with an Account that is a Domain admin, so its unlikely there is anything else that I could use.

Comment: Ownership could be an issue but are any of those files it is complaining about open in the system?

Comment: Matt, I can't even access that path in the GUI even when I set the owner to Administrator of the server and proped perms down. Its not an open file either as I can manually delete profiles all day long.

Comment: If you're using windows 7 or later, your attempt is going to fail.  The computer will create a temporary login the next time the person logs in.  The proper way to delete a user profile is to use System Properties.  Deleting a profile there removes the registry data and all user folders.

Comment: Well my attempt is failing for completely different reasons. The script will remove the registry entries as well as the profile folder *if* I could figure out a way around the access issue. I'm also not worried about temp log ins considering that the users I want to remove no longer work for the company. While using System Properties would be nice, I don't know of an interactive way of using that through powershell and the server has over 500 profiles on it.